# Right click to select item in table java fx

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I have two tables in java fx.
The first is the master, when I select an item from the first table its details must be shown in the second table.
I need an event where I can know which row was selected.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try listening to the selected item property of the table's selection model

```
    masterTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            populateSecondTable(newValue);
        }
    });
```